# Order of execution for console statements for different browsers

Tags: javascript, for-loop, console.log

I've tested the following code in both Firefox (32) and Chrome (38) so far

```
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(startTime);

var data = [];
var tCat = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("");
var dataPoints = 2000000;

for ( var i = 0; i < dataPoints; i++ ) {
    var r = Math.random;
    data.push({
        value: Math.pow(1 - Math.cos((r() * Math.PI) / 2), 3),
        cost: +r().toFixed(2),
        category: tCat[Math.floor(r() * tCat.length)]
    });
}

var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log(endTime);
console.log(endTime - startTime);
```

You can view it at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcucnc9q/4/)

In Firefox, it seems all three console statements fire at the same time, *after* the loop finishes execution, but in Chrome the first console statement is shown before the loop begins execution.  The code itself works as intended but the execution of the first console statement in Firefox is bewildering.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Is the actual execution delayed or is all of the output just buffered until the code execution completes?

Comment: You JSFiddle works as expected on my Firefox (v 33.0 )

Comment: @MarcoCI I updated Firefox to 33.0 and I still get all three console logs at once.

Comment: console.log calls are asynchronous, so the logged time will be the correct one, but it could be shown on the WebConsole in a different time... maybe in a different order

Comment: @PabloLozano delayed, yes, but surely not in a different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Consoles are not governed by any standard and depend on the browser.

It works as expected. *Try adding breakpoints* and step through each line in the code, and you'll see that they execute as expected. A much more crude approach is paralyze your script with `alert()`.

However, behavior is still vendor-dependent. No guarantees.